# loop within loop mysql count

Tags: php, mysql

I've setup a few tables to represent different products as some products have different attributes to others.

I am trying to do a count of how many items are listed from a specific city. My sql statement is as follows:

```
Select count(*) as count from location, tbl_books where location.city = tbl_books.location && location.city = 'London' && location.country = 'United Kingdom'

Select count(*) as count from location, tbl_clothes where location.city = tbl_clothes.location && location.city = 'London' && location.country = 'United Kingdom'
```

This loops to count results in all cities within the country. These loops represents the inner loop. The outer loop loops through the different category tables.

I find this is not very efficient and was wondering whether anyone might be able to suggest any way of dealing with this problem. I was thinking of just creating a master table with cities and category fields and just incrementing the count in the master table everytime a new item is added from a particular city.

Comment: I can't see any loops there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you the book counts for all cities and countries, no loops needed:

```sql
SELECT 
    location.country, 
    location.city,
    COUNT(*) as `count` 
FROM locaton
INNER JOIN tbl_books ON location.city = tbl_books.location 
GROUP BY location.country, location.city
ORDER BY location.country, location.city
```

Results will look like this:

```
country          |   city    |   count
-----------------+-----------+-----------
France           | Paris     |  1
United Kingdom   | Belfast   |  2
United Kingdom   | London    |  3
...
```

Comment: This is great, how would I go about adding these counts to counts from other category tables?

Comment: I'm not sure, that depends on how many tables and their structure. Maybe you should ask a separate question about that.

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL query will return the count and location.city values as one query by joining the location table.city key with the tbl_books.location key.

```
Select count(*) as count, location.city 
from location, tbl_books 
where location.city = tbl_books.location
group by location.city
```

Answer (score 1):

This will sum up all books by city, for all cities in the UK (out of my head, untested):

```
select tbl_books.location, count(tbl_books.location) as count
from location inner join tbl_books on location.city = tbl_books.location
where location.country = 'United Kingdom'
group by tbl_books.location
```

The result should look something like this:

```
location  |  count
--------------------
London    |  5
--------------------
Newcastle |  1
--------------------
...       | ...
```